# Computing All The Possible Substrings of a Given String

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, permutation, pseudocode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find all substrings of a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099732/how-to-find-all-substrings-of-a-string-in-php)
>   [Find all subsets of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023081/find-all-subsets-of-a-list)

How can I compute all the possible substrings of a string? For example given a string ABCDE. All its possible substrings will be

A,
B,
C,
D,
E,
AB,
BC,
CD,
DE,
ABC,
BCD,
CDE,
ABCD,
BCDE,
ABCDE

Thanks! A pseudocode will be highly appreciated. :D

Comment: This type of question has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728972 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592039 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023081/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780935/ , etc. etc. Just search on "powerset" or "subset".

Comment: I disagree with both Ken and bobbymcr. While it is true that the linked question is "how to find substrings of a string?" it seems to involve some heavy PHP with minimal explanation, as do the answers. All of the links bobbymcr linked are completely separate problems, though related (substrings are not subsets). Upon cursory inspection, I cannot find a similar language-agnostic question with clear answers given in pseudocode.

Comment: @ninjagecko: On second reading, I see that you're right -- the OP seems to want something more specialized than pure subsets, but something like substrings with fully connected elements (e.g. from ABC -> AB and BC, but not AC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use two for-loops:

```
generate substrings(string):
    for start in [0,1,...,string.length-1]:
        for end in [start,...,string.length-1]:
            yield string[start...end]
```

You can also do it this way with two for-loops:

```
generate substrings(string):
    for substringLength in [1,2,...,string.length]:
        for start in range [0,1,...,string.length-substringLength]:
            yield string[start...(start+substringLength-1)]
    yield ""
```

You probably want to include the empty string `""` in the sequence you return as well, as it is a substring of all strings.

You also need to consider if it is valid to yield a duplicate string multiple times (e.g. do you return "ABA" twice as a substring of "ABABA"?). If the answer is no, merely make a hashtable called `alreadyYielded`, and whenever you yield, abort if you've already yielded the string, otherwise add the value to the hashtable in case you see it again. For example:

```
seen = new HashTable()
...
        substring = string[...]
        if substring not in seen:
            seen.add(substring)
            yield substring
...
```

Comment: Thanks @ninjagecko! BTW, how about computing the number of such substrings? As given in the example above I have 5 characters. P(5) = 15 as shown above. I wanted to know the function P to get the computation of the number of all the possible substrings of a string. Thanks. :D

Comment: It should be 2^n since it's the same problem as finding the number of subsets of a set

Comment: It's not 2^n @ÓscarLópez since 2^5 is not 15. :P

Comment: My mistake, the number of substrings is not the same as the powerset of the sequence of its characters!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez True! But that's ok. :D

Comment: Ah! The answer to my own question will be ((n+1)n)/2). :D

Comment: neilmarion: if you look at the number of strings the second loop returns, it looks like this: `LENGTH+(LENGTH-1)+(LENGTH-2)+...+1`, which is equal to `LENGTH*(LENGTH+1)/2`

Comment: I get a syntax error for `...`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 2-cent answer:

```
for (indexOfFirstLetterOfString = 0; indexOfFirstLetterOfString < string.length; indexOfFirstLetterOfString++) {

   for (indexOfLastLetterOfString = indexOfFirstLetterOfString + 1; indexOfLastLetterOfString < string.length; indexOfLastLetterOfString++) {

        addToArrayOfStrings ( string.substring (indexOfFirstLetterOfString, indexOfLastLetterOfString - indexOfFirstLetterOfString))
        incrementCounter();

    }
}
```

To get the number of combinations, simply add a counter to the inner loop.

For instance, in perl, this might look like:

```
$a = "ABCDE";

$numberOfSubstrings = 0;

for ($indexOfFirstLetter = 0; $indexOfFirstLetter <= length($a); $indexOfFirstLetter++) {

    for ($indexOfLastLetter = $indexOfFirstLetter + 1; $indexOfLastLetter <= length($a); $indexOfLastLetter++)  {
        print substr($a, $indexOfFirstLetter, $indexOfLastLetter - $indexOfFirstLetter) . "\n";

        $numberOfSubStrings++;
    }
}

print "Number of substrings: " . $numberOfSubStrings;
```