# Find all Occurences of Every Substring in String

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to find all occurrences of sub-strings in a main string (of all lengths). My function takes one string and then returns a dictionary of every sub-string (which occurs more than once, of course) and how many times it occurs (format of the dictionary: `{substring: # of occurrences, ...}`). I am using `collections.Counter(s)` to help me with it.

Here is my function:

```
from collections import Counter

def patternFind(s):
    patterns = {}
    for index in range(1, len(s)+1)[::-1]:
        d = nChunks(s, step=index)
        parts = dict(Counter(d))
        patterns.update({elem: parts[elem] for elem in parts.keys() if parts[elem] > 1})
    return patterns

def nChunks(iterable, start=0, step=1):
    return [iterable[i:i+step] for i in range(start, len(iterable), step)]
```

I have a string, `data` with about 2500 random letters (in a random order). However, there are 2 strings inserted into it (random points). Say this string is 'TEST'. `data.count('TEST')` returns 2. However, `patternFind(data)['TEST']` gives me a `KeyError`. Therefore, my program does not detect the two strings in it.

What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Edit: My method of creating testing-instances:

```
def createNewTest():
    n = randint(500, 2500)
    x, y = randint(500, n), randint(500, n)
    s = ''
    for i in range(n):
        s += choice(uppercase)
        if i == x or i == y: s += "TEST"
    return s
```

Comment: Can you show how you are inserting "TEST" into your string?  Your code seems to work perfectly for me.  I created a test string with `s = [random.choice(string.letters+string.digits) for i in range(2500)]` then inserted "TEST" at a couple of places using `s[ind:ind+4] = "TEST"` and joined the list into a single string with `s = ''.join(s)`.  Calling `out = patternFind(s)` gave me a dict where `out['TEST'] == 2`.

Comment: @Vorticity Edited my code with how I am creating the string. I tried it with 100 strings, and only 29 were correct. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I guess my first reply was wrong.  The code doesn't work as is.  I'm out of time on this for now, but at least I can give you a hint.  Start using a MUCH shorter string (say `n = randint(20, 40)`) and print `parts` every time through the loop.  You will find that you are not looking at every possibility.  Your find routine is about to get a lot more complicated and I think you'd be better off trying to go back to the original problem and figure out what it is that you are TRULY looking for.

Comment: Or, it looks like mezzomondo may have a good answer for you.

Comment: @Vorticity Yeah it's because of the starting point of `nChunks`. I created a way to find ALL substrings, but for a 2500-character file, it had 3.1M or so substrings (some may have been duplicates), which inevitably slowed my program down.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something. Are you only trying to generate a dictionary with all the substrings as keys? Or only those which occur more than once? Why are you not simply constructing this dictionary in a forward fashion? In terms of the algorithmics, it doesn't make sense to use finds or regexs.

Comment: Is your `createNewTest()` the actual code you use?  Because it can generate a string as small as 500 characters.  Also, using `+=` to generate string longer than a few pieces is *very* slow.

Comment: @EthanFurman I was just using that to make test files in large amounts (100 or so). But yes, that was my actual code.

Comment: +1 for provoking this "contest" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While jurgenreza has explained why your program didn't work, the solution is still quite slow. If you only examine substrings `s` for which you know that `s[:-1]` repeats, you get a much faster solution (typically a hundred times faster and more):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pfind(prefix, sequences):
    collector = defaultdict(list)
    for sequence in sequences:
        collector[sequence[0]].append(sequence)
    for item, matching_sequences in collector.items():
        if len(matching_sequences) >= 2:
            new_prefix = prefix + item
            yield (new_prefix, len(matching_sequences))
            for r in pfind(new_prefix, [sequence[1:] for sequence in matching_sequences]):
                yield r

def find_repeated_substrings(s):
    s0 = s + " "
    return pfind("", [s0[i:] for i in range(len(s))])
```

If you want a dict, you call it like this:

```
result = dict(find_repeated_substrings(s))
```

On my machine, for a run with 2247 elements, it took 0.02 sec, while the original (corrected) solution took 12.72 sec.

(Note that this is a rather naive implementation; using indexes of instead of substrings should be even faster.)

**Edit:** The following variant works with other sequence types (not only strings). Also, it doesn't need a sentinel element.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pfind(s, length, ends):
    collector = defaultdict(list)
    if ends[-1] >= len(s):
        del ends[-1]
    for end in ends:
        if end < len(s):
            collector[s[end]].append(end)
    for key, matching_ends in collector.items():
        if len(matching_ends) >= 2:
            end = matching_ends[0]
            yield (s[end - length: end + 1], len(matching_ends))
            for r in pfind(s, length + 1, [end + 1 for end in matching_ends if end < len(s)]):
                yield r


def find_repeated_substrings(s):
    return pfind(s, 0, list(range(len(s))))
```

This still has the problem that very long substrings will exceed recursion depth. You might want to catch the exception.

Comment: This is much faster, thanks! Can you explain how each step works, though?

Comment: @WolframH - This is by far the fastest solution and I am awarding the bounty here. The recursive solution completely re-defines the problem and is most elegant. One downside: if the sub-string occurs very frequently in the main string, then the function will exceed recursion depth and crash; the exception should be caught and either fail gracefully or revert to one of the slower solutions. You may want to note this in the answer? Congrats again!

Comment: I'm still not sure how it works (I haven't worked with generators often); I tried changing to to work with lists (converting it to a tuple) but I couldn't get it to work with that. Could you add a subsection with how it would work for lists (or any non-string iterable object)? Thanks :3

Answer (score 4):

### Using Regular Expressions

Apart from the `count()` method you described, regex is an obvious alternative

```
import re

needle = r'TEST'

haystack = 'khjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESTjklajhkhzkhjkzahklahjTESTkahklagh'
pattern = re.compile(needle)

print len(re.findall(pattern, haystack))
```

### Short Cut

If you need to build a dictionary of substrings, possibly you can do this with only subset of those strings. Assuming you know the `needle` you are looking for in the `data` then you only need the dictionary of substrings of `data` that are the same length of `needle`. This is very fast.

```
from collections import Counter

needle = "TEST"

def gen_sub(s, len_chunk):
    for start in range(0, len(s)-len_chunk+1):
        yield s[start:start+len_chunk]

data = 'khjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESTjklajhkhzkhjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESz'
parts = Counter([sub for sub in gen_sub(data, len(needle))])

print parts[needle]
```

### Brute Force: building dictionary of all substrings

If you need to have a count of all possible substrings, this works but it is very slow:

```
from collections import Counter

def gen_sub(s):
    for start in range(0, len(s)):
        for end in range(start+1, len(s)+1):
            yield s[start:end]

data = 'khjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESTjklajhkhz'
parts = Counter([sub for sub in gen_sub(data)])

print parts['TEST']
```

Substring generator adapted from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305463/1290420

Comment: It takes very long for the 2500-letter string, though.

Comment: I want to find the patterns of every substring in the main string (only given the main string). I don't necessarily need to do it brute-force, but that's how I thought of doing it originally. If there is another way, please tell me about it.

Comment: Added two variants that are faster than the brute force method. Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know the "needle". I tried doing `d = {}`, then `for i in range(1, len(data)+1): parts.update(dict(Counter([sub for sub in gen_sub(data, i)])))` but this takes very long and actually froze my computer.

Comment: Finding all possible substrings, of all possible lengths, in a string of 2500 characters **is** going to take an inordinate length of time. You may need to go back to the analysis of the problem and choose a different way of solving it. I will leave my answer here to show others what _doesn't_ work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `nChunks` function. It does not give you all the chunks that are necessary.

Let's consider a test string:

```
s='1test2345test'
```

For the chunks of size 4 your `nChunks` function gives this output:

```
>>>nChunks(s, step=4)
['1tes', 't234', '5tes', 't']
```

But what you really want is:

```
>>>def nChunks(iterable, start=0, step=1):
    return [iterable[i:i+step] for i in range(len(iterable)-step+1)]
>>>nChunks(s, step=4)
['1tes', 'test', 'est2', 'st23', 't234', '2345', '345t', '45te', '5tes', 'test']
```

You can see that this way there are two `'test'` chunks and your `patternFind(s)` will work like a charm:

```
>>> patternFind(s)
{'tes': 2, 'st': 2, 'te': 2, 'e': 2, 't': 4, 'es': 2, 'est': 2, 'test': 2, 's': 2}
```

Comment: Elegant, but no different in essence than my short cut function. The problem is only partly the generation of substrings; the real issue is how long it takes with a string of 2500 characters.

Comment: @gauden I hadn't read the comments closely. I focused on what was asked in the question; There, you ask "What have I done wrong?" and there is no mention of the speed. Maybe you should create another question addressing the size and speed of the operation.

Comment: @gauden sorry I thought you are the OP. :)

Comment: @jurgenreza This is the fastest method (that I've found)... for the 2500-character file, took 19 seconds, which is significantly better than the rest... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here you can find a solution that uses a recursive wrapper around `string.find()` that searches all the occurences of a substring in a main string.
The `collectallchuncks()` function returns a `defaultdict` whith all the substrings as keys and for each substring a list of all the indexes where the substring is found in the main string.

```
import collections

# Minimum substring size, may be 1
MINSIZE = 3

# Recursive wrapper
def recfind(p, data, pos, acc):
    res = data.find(p, pos)
    if res == -1:
        return acc
    else:
        acc.append(res)
        return recfind(p, data, res+1, acc)

def collectallchuncks(data):
    res = collections.defaultdict(str)
    size = len(data)
    for base in xrange(size):
        for seg in xrange(MINSIZE, size-base+1):
            chunk = data[base:base+seg]
            if data.count(chunk) > 1:
                res[chunk] = recfind(chunk, data, 0, [])
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = 'khjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESTjklajhkhzkhjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESz'
    allchuncks = collectallchuncks(data)
    print 'TEST', allchuncks['TEST']
    print 'hklag', allchuncks['hklag']
```

EDIT: If you just need the number of occurrences of each substring in the main string you can easily obtain it getting rid of the recursive function:

```
import collections

MINSIZE = 3

def collectallchuncks2(data):
    res = collections.defaultdict(str)
    size = len(data)
    for base in xrange(size):
        for seg in xrange(MINSIZE, size-base+1):
            chunk = data[base:base+seg]
            cnt = data.count(chunk)
            if cnt > 1:
                res[chunk] = cnt
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = 'khjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESTjklajhkhzkhjkzahklahjTESTkahklaghTESz'
    allchuncks = collectallchuncks2(data)
    print 'TEST', allchuncks['TEST']
    print 'hklag', allchuncks['hklag']
```

Comment: This is similar to what gauden had except in one function. For a file with about 2500 words, it took 46 seconds, which is pretty long.

Comment: I'm a little skeptical that you are going to find a faster method using python.  This might be a point where you want to drop to C for speed or re-think what it is that you need.

Comment: @Vorticity: see my answer; it can be much faster even in python.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer.  Thanks for reminding me to come back to this question and congrats on the bounty.