# algorithm for finding unique any size combination of numbers in c

Tags: c, algorithm

I need a clean c code to find out combination of numbers.
Any number of numbers and any size of combination.
Such as for {1,2,3}
output should be {1,2,3,12,13,23,123}, note 23 and 32 as same.
Is there any clean c program for that ?

Best regards,

Comment: combinations 123,132,213,231,312,321 are missing

Comment: There probably are many nice programs for this. But we're not going to do your homework for you. Please show us what you have tried yourself, and tell us what problem you have with *your* code.

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for already existing software requrement

Comment: You want the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) without the empty set. That should be good [Google fodder](https://www.google.de/search?q=power+set+algorithm+c).

Comment: That sounds like finding all the subsets of set problem. This question comes with pseudo-code of how this could be done. Just try to implement it in C language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592039/recursively-find-subsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Here's a way using bit manipulation.

Let the given set be ***a***.

The code for this is pretty small. Understand the following and you will understand how that tiny snippet of code works.

The first thing you have to realize here is that you are finding the **(2<sup>n</sup> - 1)** subset of the given set.

Any set has **2<sup>n</sup>** subsets and here, you have excluded the *null* set. Hence **(2<sup>n</sup> - 1)**

Now, to generate these subsets we need an algorithm.

> Observe the following:
>
> ---
>
> 001    ---  1
>
> 010    ---  2
>
> 011    ---  3
>
> 100    ---  4
>
> 101    ---  5
>
> 110    ---  6
>
> 111    ---  7
>
> The left digits constitute the binary representation of the right decimal numbers.

If we write out for binary numbers with 4 digits, there would be 15 combinations. Notice that I am excluding the combination where all digits are zero in the above example.

In general, for *n-bit* binary numbers, there are **(2<sup>n</sup> - 1)** different combinations of the digits. We can use this to generate the subsets, in a very simple fashion.

For every element in the set, you are allowed to:

1. Choose the element for the current subset.
2. Don't choose that element for the current subset.
3. Leave out the situation where you choose none.

(Hence, there are **(2<sup>n</sup> - 1)** subsets)

Now, I say do the following:

```
for i in [1,2^n - 1]:
     Let b = binary representation of i.
     for every jth bit in b:
         if the jth bit is set:
             print a[j]
     print a newline character.
```

Here is the C code:

```
// include your headers

int isJthBitSet(int i,int j)  
{
// returns 1 if jth bit is set in the binary representation of i.
    return (i & (1 << j));
}

int main()
{
     int n = 3;               // The size of the set for example. 
     int a[] = {1,2,3};      // the given set, for example.
     for(int i = 1; i < (1 << n); i++)   // i is from 1...2^n - 1
     {
          for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) // for every jth bit in the n-bit representation of i
          {
                if(isJthBitSet(i,j)) // if the bit is set
                    printf("%d ", a[j]); // print the corresponding element
          }
          printf("\n");
     }
    return 0;
}
```

And that would be pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

While I normally frown upon showing complete solutions, based on a few relatively recent similar questions and their answers, it seems that some examples of how to solve these types of combinatorics problems are warranted.

An easy way to construct all unique sets with `k` elements out of `n` elements, is to use `k` nested loops, where the loop indexes are always in increasing order. For example, to print all unique 3 char triplets, from a set of `N` chars, you could use

```
    const char all[N] = ...;
    char set[4];
    size_t i, j, k;

    set[3] = '\0'; /* End of string mark */

    for (i = 0; i < N-2; i++) {
        set[0] = all[i];

        for (j = i+1; j < N-1; j++) {
            set[1] = all[j];

            for (k = j+1; k < N; k++) {
                set[2] = all[k];

                puts(set);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the OP wants all unique subsets with *up to* `k` elements out of a set of `n` elements, which means we need cannot use nested loops as above (since we don't know the maximum `k`). Explicitly, anyway. Instead, we need to think of how to rewrite that.

To get a better grip on the construction, let's look at say the three-out-of-five case. The ten result sets are

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

There is clear order, and clear logic: increase the rightmost, unless it would become too large. Then, find the next index to the left that we can increment without going over (keeping enough elements for those on its right side). If we cannot increment even the leftmost without going over, we have produced all sets. (If you think about it, this is also quite a straightforward implementation of variably-nested loops.) After incrementing, set the elements to the right in ascending order.

In most cases, we'd like some sort of structure or object that keep tracks of the state and the current subset, with functions to initialize, free, and to switch to the next subset. Here is one possibility:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>


typedef struct {
    char    *buffer;    /* Symbol buffer */
    size_t   length;    /* Number of symbols to choose */
    size_t  *index;     /* Index of each symbol */
    char    *symbol;    /* Array of symbols */
    size_t   symbols;   /* Number of symbols to choose from */
} generator;


void generator_free(generator *const g)
{
    if (g) {
        free(g->buffer);
        free(g->index);
        free(g->symbol);
        g->buffer  = NULL;
        g->length  = 0;
        g->index   = NULL;
        g->symbol  = NULL;
        g->symbols = 0;
    }
}


const char *generator_current(generator *const g, const char *const none)
{
    return (g && g->buffer) ? g->buffer : none;
}


int generator_init(generator *const g, const char *const symbol, const size_t choose)
{
    const size_t symbols = (symbol) ? strlen(symbol) : 0;
    size_t       i;

    if (!g || symbols < 1 || choose < 1 || choose > symbols)
        return EINVAL;

    g->buffer = malloc(choose + 1);
    g->index  = malloc((choose + 1) * sizeof g->index[0]);
    g->symbol = malloc(symbols + 1);
    if (!g->buffer || !g->index || !g->symbol) {
        free(g->buffer);
        free(g->index);
        free(g->symbol);
        g->buffer  = NULL;
        g->length  = 0;
        g->index   = NULL;
        g->symbol  = NULL;
        g->symbols = 0;
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    memcpy(g->buffer, symbol, choose);
    g->buffer[choose] = '\0';
    g->length = choose;

    for (i = 0; i < choose; i++)
        g->index[i] = i;
    g->index[choose] = symbols;

    memcpy(g->symbol, symbol, symbols);
    g->symbol[symbols] = '\0';
    g->symbols = symbols;

    return 0;
}


int generator_next(generator *const g)
{
    size_t i;

    if (!g || !g->buffer || g->length < 1 || !g->index)
        return EINVAL;

    if (g->index[0] >= g->symbols - g->length)
        return ENOENT;

    if (++g->index[g->length - 1] >= g->symbols) {

        i = g->length - 1;
        while (i > 0 && g->index[i] + 1 >= g->symbols - i)
            i--;

        g->index[i]++;

        if (!i && g->index[0] > g->symbols - g->length) {
            memset(g->buffer, '\0', g->length + 1);
            return ENOENT;
        }

        while (i++ < g->length)
            g->index[i] = g->index[i-1] + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < g->length; i++)
        g->buffer[i] = g->symbol[g->index[i]];
    g->buffer[g->length] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

`generator_current()` provides the current set (as a string). Instead of returning `NULL` when there is no valid set, it returns the string you specify as the second parameter. (It's just for convenience, no real reason behind this.)

`generator_free()` discards the generator, `generator_init()` initializes a new generator, and `generator_next()` advances the generator to the next subset.

Note that `generator_init()` also initializes the first subset; the one where the elements are chosen consecutively. (Although the `->symbol` is only a character array containing all characters in the overall set, the function appends an end-of-string mark, so you can treat it as a string, too.)

The first if clause in `generator_next()` just makes sure the generator is initialized; it's just a sanity check. The second one checks if the generator is complete.

The third if clause in `generator_next()` increments the rightmost index, changing the last element in the subset. If it runs out of valid elements, the while loop searches for the index `i` for an index that can be incremented without running out of elements. Note that because the indexes are in ascending order (that ensures unique subsets), this must remember to account for the elements needed for the rest of the position.

If `i` becomes zero and overflows, there are no more subsets, and the `->buffer` member is cleared to an empty string (just in case).

Otherwise, the second while loop fills in the indexes to the right of `i` with consecutive values. (See the above example for three-out-of-five, the case where the first element changes from 1 to 2, for illustration of why this is needed.)

Finally, the for loop is used to copy the elements from the `->symbol` array, according to the indexes, to `->buffer`.

For the askers case, the size of the subsets varies, so to generate all subsets, a loop is needed. For example:

```
generator g;
size_t    i;

for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (generator_init(&g, "123", i)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "generator_init() failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    do {

        /* Print the set and a newline */
        puts(generator_current(&g, ""));

    } while (!generator_next(&g));
    generator_free(&g);
}
```

For testing, I used the following helper function and `main()`:

```
int parse_size(const char *s, size_t *const dst)
{
    const char   *endptr = NULL;
    unsigned long value;
    size_t        result;
    int           skip = -1;

    if (!s || !*s)
        return EINVAL;

    errno = 0;
    value = strtoul(s, (char **)&endptr, 0);
    if (errno)
        return errno;
    if (!endptr || endptr == s)
        return EEXIST;

    (void)sscanf(endptr, " %n", &skip);
    if (skip > 0)
        endptr += skip;
    if (*endptr)
        return EEXIST;

    result = (size_t)value;
    if ((unsigned long)result != value)
        return EDOM;

    if (dst)
        *dst = result;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    generator g;
    size_t    symbols, length, len;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s DIGITS LENGTH\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This will print each unique set of LENGTH characters from DIGITS,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "one set per line.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    symbols = (argv[1]) ? strlen(argv[1]) : 0;
    if (symbols < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No DIGITS specified.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_size(argv[2], &length) || length < 1 || length > symbols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid LENGTH.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (len = 1; len <= length; len++) {

        if (generator_init(&g, argv[1], len)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Generator initialization failed.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        do {
            puts(generator_current(&g, ""));
        } while (!generator_next(&g));

        generator_free(&g);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In Linux, I prefer to compile the above using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -O2 main.c -o example`. The original question asked for

```
./example 123 2
```

which outputs

```
1
2
3
12
13
23
```

A larger example is much more interesting. For example,

```
./example 12345 3
```

lists all one, two, and three-digit sets from the set of first five digits. The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
12
13
14
15
23
24
25
34
35
45
123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345
```

Questions?